# Rewrite rule for "/A/B" to "/B?id=A"

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm tring to rewrite the following URL:

```
example.com/[name1]/[name2]
```

to:

```
example.com/[name2].htm?id=[name1]
```

I'm tring this rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/(\d+)/(.+)/ /$2?id=$1 last;
```

but it does seems to be working. Can someone help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the .htm in your rewrite

Is it correct that the name1 is always made up out of all digits as you regexp assumes?

Updated:

```
location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.+)/$ {
  rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.+)/ /$2.htm?id=$1 last; 
}
```

basicaly what we're doing here is:

- we match with the regex on the location, this selects the url's we want to rewrite
- in the location block we then do the rewrite

(note: we need to repeat the regex because the rewrite directive resets the contents of the $1 and $2 backreferences, if we where doing something else we could just use those directly inside the location block)

Comment: [name1] is a normal string (a-z,0-9)

Comment: should I add something like `location ~` or `if`?

Comment: then your regex is wrong, \d only matches 0-9, updated my answer accordingly

Comment: either "location ~ regex {}" or an "if regex {...}" will work, but yes add one of the other to limit your rewrite to http requests of the form you want to rewrite

Comment: I only want to rewrite when url is like /[name1]/[name2]